# data pull in java

Tags: java

how do i pull enum values or mutlivalued data from my sql to a java list box?

Comment: question is rather unclear. Please put some effort into letting us know what exactly you want. And what are the technologies.

Comment: Your sql? Oh.. did you mean MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You pull data from MySQL using JDBC; here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) if you don't know how to do that.

Here's a Swing [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  If you want JSP and web, here's another for [JSP](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Manually. Unlike .NET, Java has no support to map DB columns to UI elements out of the box. Frameworks like Hibernate can map DB columns to Enums (and other types). After that, you're basically on your own.

There are a couple of frameworks in the making that try to make this more simple but all of them have severe disadvantages.

[EDIT] Let's have a look at a couple of examples:

- [Metawidget](http://www.metawidget.org/) seems the best option today. The 1.0 was released just a month ago. There was some catch when I examined it three years ago but I don't remember anymore.
- [Spring-RCP](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/) is probably dead (no updates for a year). Biggest drawback: You need a classed and an XML files, so things that belong to each other are in different files.
- [Glazed Lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) is mainly focused on displaying lists in tables.
- [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) have some data binding support based on Java Beans which isn't ideal. For example, the Java Beans API has no support for operations on maps and lists. Instead of saying "show the elements of this list in that table", you have to create a model which listens somehow to list changes (good luck getting that right).

  Apart from that, documentation for both ... could be better. Most demos go "add a button to a window and slap 'hello world' on it". What I'm missing is simple things like master/detail views, displaying millions of objects in a table, etc.

Comment: "There are a couple of frameworks in the making that try to make this more simple but all of them have severe disadvantages": can you elaborate on the severe disadvantages part?